# Addition of two B-spline curves

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve, spline

Suppose I have two B-splines, both with the same degree, $p$, and uniformly distributed knots, but with different numbers of knots and control points.

Is it possible to sum the two splines to obtain a new B-spline?

Comment: And if so... how?

Comment: You probably can, you have to insert knot in both curves, then just sum the obtained BSplines. Since the degree is the same knot insertion implies they belong to the same spline space, at that point literally sums the obtained spline.

Comment: Are the curves defined on the same domain? If they are, then the sum could be expressed as a b spline curve where the knots are the union of the knots of original curves (just do knot insertion on both curves).

Comment: They are on the same domain so the above suggestions should work. Thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way to perform this without increasing the number of control points (above the number of control points in the largest addend)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can just add knots until the two curves have the same knot sequence. They will then have the same number of control points, and "adding" the curves is just adding corresponding control points.

The final knot sequence of each curve will be the union of the two original knot sequences. You say the original knot sequences were uniform. So, if we rescale both of them to the interval $[0,1]$, they will have the form
$$
\left\{\frac{i}{m} : 0 \le i \le m \right\} \quad \text{and} \quad
\left\{\frac{j}{n} : 0 \le j \le n \right\}
$$
These sets are not likely to have many members in common, so, when you form the union, you will probably end up with a knot sequence with roughly $m+n$ entries.

If you know that you're going to be doing this sort of thing a lot, and you're worried about "knot explosion", one idea is to choose the original $m$ and $n$ to be powers of $2$.

Comment: If I am dealing with more than two B splines,( constructed on different knots vectors, always on the same domain and with same degree) could it be the case that after summing all the knot sequences I end up with "irrelevant" knots? Is there any way to get rid of those?

Comment: The short answer is "no". If you remove a knot from the combined knot sequence, then you will remove it from the curve that originally introduced it, and this will change the shape of that curve. The change may be very small, but it will almost always be non-zero.